# Как отсортировать данные из связанных таблиц SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

Дано две таблицы SQL.

Первая table_header

[image: table_header]

Вторая table_position

[image: table_position]

Обе таблицы связаны между собой по столбцу id=id_pos

Необходимо вывести все документы из таблицы table_header, где в таблице table_position по данному документу более 3-ех позиций.
Из условия должно выдать только документ с id = 3

[image: Результат]

Такое возможно?

Answer (score 0):

```sql
SELECT *
FROM table_header
JOIN ( SELECT id_pos id
       FROM table_position
       GROUP BY id
       HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT position) >= 3 ) cnt USING (id)
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]